# Leaking memory when calling exit(0)

Tags: c++, exit

I read before that:

> When you exit a C++ program by calling the exit() function, the object
> destructors are not run. This can result in Valgrind reporting memory
> leaks.

But what if I'm waiting for user input and if it's exit then I want to exit the program, how may I do that?

I am scanning input in a function called by another one called by main.
Like this:

```
void main()
{
    func1();
}

void func1()
{
    func2();
}

void func2()
{
    std::string str;
    getline(std::cin, str);
    if (str=="exit") exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem with code?

Comment: @KungfuFrog added some code, I'm looking to exit program normally not using exit(0)

Comment: my program is like a shell

Comment: [`std::exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) has a long list of guarantees about what is and is not freed, released, or cast into the fires of Mount Doom. The ol' C function [`exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) I'm not so sure about. So I just don't use it. Make sure you're calling `std::exit`, then sit back and relax.

Comment: @PaulSanders Probably does. Problem is I'm not seeing any outright guarantees. Time to dive into the C++ Standard, I guess.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that guarantees stack unrolling and destruction of local variables, but I'll admit my Standard-Fu is weak..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit):

> Returning from the the main function, either by a return statement or by reaching the end of the function, executes `exit()`, passing the argument of the return statement (or ​0​ if implicit return was used) as exit_code.

In other words, calling `exit` is the same as returning from `main` (or falling off the end), which in turn calls the destructors of any statically allocated objects before the program finally quits.

That said, [`std::exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) offers the appropriate guarantees, so that's the one to use.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xZHJvXTPgJiCBxIi)

---

**Edit:** If you want to ensure that variables allocated at local scope are destroyed (see discussion) then you could throw a custom exception at the point where you want to exit the program and catch it in `main`, e.g.

```
class ExitProgramException {};

void foo ()
{
    ...
    if (exit_program)
    {
        ExitProgramException e;
        throw e;
    }
}

void bar ()
{
    foo ();
}

int main ()
{
    try
    {
        bar ();
    }
    catch (const ExitProgramException& e)
    {
    }
}
```

This should ensure that the stack is unwound correctly.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DaPKGXuG75ZhFCZo)

Comment: We're going to have to disagree on how to interpret that, I think. I read it as "When you return from `main`, `exit` is called." I don't read that as, "When `exit` is called stack unrolls all the way back through `main`."

Comment: @user4581301 That's not what I'm saying.  I'm saying that `exit` calls all the relevant destructors and then quits the program.  There's no need to unwind the stack.  I'm pretty sure that `exit` and `std::exit` do the same thing, FWIW.

Comment: Maybe link to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) which explains how memory clean up is better? I presume OP is asking for C++ std::exit by tag.

Comment: @LouisGo Yes, thank you.  Calling `std::exit` certainly makes the most sense in a C++ program.

Comment: I looked at your link again. We are in agreement, but I'm not sure what you're showing in your example is what's being asked. I think this is more what they're after: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QvIPzAVs5Z6HNhro

Comment: @user4581301 Yes you're correct..`std::exit` in cppreference specifically stated about  "Stack is not unwound: destructors of variables with automatic storage duration are not called." It seems the only way to gracefully exit the program is go to the main and exit.. No shortcut..

Comment: @LouisGo son of a gun. So it does. Could have saved myself a lot of standard-digging.

Comment: Since I have now caught up with what everyone is on about, I have added a suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `if (str=="exit") return;`

Comment: Which is basically a no-op in this example, since `func2()` is going to exit normally right after that statement anyway.

Comment: This example is clearly simplified to the level of uselessness. But if the real code actually contains such an `if` with `exit()` then replacing it with `return` can fix the problem.

Comment: Well, that really depends on whether `func1()` does other things when `func2()` exits.  It may not be desirable to perform those other operations if an exit is requested. The code, as it currently stands, doesn't know the difference.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, it depends. But you do not know what these functions do except what is shown here, and I do not know, either. So I comment the code which I can see,  and in this code my change is reasonable with respect to possible development of the code in the context of variables destruction. At least I think so.